# matrix plot labeling with passes

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Here is a Matrix Plot with labeled cells:

```
list = {{1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}};
collab = Row[{0.1*#}] & /@ Range[4];
rowlab = Row[{0.1*#}] & /@ Range[3];
rowticks = Thread[{Range[3], rowlab}];
colticks = Thread[{Range[4], collab}];
MatrixPlot[list, FrameTicks -> {rowticks, colticks}]
```

How can I pass some cells while labeling? For example, is there a way not to sign a horizontal axis where values 0.2 and 0.4 are?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to make those labels `Invisible`.

```
collab = Row[{0.1*#}] & /@ Range[4] // MapAt[Invisible, #, {{2}, {4}}] &
```

[image]